# trying to check if id exist

Tags: php, mysql

Hello im trying to check if the id exist or not what do i put on my if statement i want it to just check and insert if not exist in the database then insert. and if it exist do nothing to it.

```
function exists($date_, $account, $dimension)
{
    $sql = "SELECT account FROM ".TB_PREF."budget WHERE account=".db_escape($account)
    ." AND tran_date='$date_' AND
        id=".db_escape($dimension)." AND 
    $result = db_query($sql, "Cannot retreive transaction");

    return (db_num_rows($result) > 0);
}

function add($date_, $account, $dimension, $dimension2, $amount)
{
    $date = date2sql($date_);

    if (exists_gl_budget($date, $account, $dimension, $dimension2))

    else
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".TB_PREF."budget(tran_date,
            account, id) VALUES ('$date',
            ".db_escape($account).", ".db_escape($dimension).", "
            .db_escape($dimension2).", ".db_escape($amount).", '')";

    db_query($sql, " not be saved");
}
```

Comment: you could insert without checking and just use the IGNORE modifier in the query

Comment: how would i do that if i leave blank in the if statement gives me alot of errors

Comment: If you couldn't tell from the syntax highlighting in your question, you have some syntax errors in your code.

Comment: probably ditch the `IF` and directly go to `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead?

Comment: This is riddled with errors you should fix, like your function named `exists` where as you are using `exists_gl_budget` in the bottom script, then you have a hanging `" AND` with no close quote, then your insert statement has 3 columns but 6 values...and lastly you have all these functions that should be replaced with proper binding of parameters.

Comment: Already fix most of the bug but still i can't figure out how to not insert duplicate database if exist already keep inserting same database how to stop it from insert again if database  already exist?.